How to setup subdomain from godaddy to AWS API Gateway?
I have a simple API hosted as AWS Lambda. I setup an API Gateway facade to the lambda and everything works as expected if I use the generated URL on the stage. I would like to access my API like so https://api.dev.mycompany.com/v1/. Here is what I tried

Added a CNAME record in GoDaddy (domain registrar :-( )
Set name to api.dev
Set value to AWS generated URL excluding https and stage

When I call my API from Postman I get a 403 Forbidden and the error is Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames
Thought that made sense because whatever cert AWS is using doesn't account for api.dev.mycompany.com
Next

I created a Certificate in AWS for the domain api.dev.mycompany.com
Added another CNAME record in GoDaddy using the name and value in AWS Certificate manager. After a few minutes the Certificate became valid
Created a custom domain in AWS Gateway for api.dev.mycompany.com and used the cert created in step 1

However I still get the same Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames error.
Any advice highly appreciated.

You should create domain record for dev.mycompany.com and in this domain define host api.dev.mycompany.com

@RomeoNinov thanks for the comment. However I am unable to buy dev.mycompany.com on GoDaddy. Only devmycompany.com seems to be available.
Can you elaborate on create domain record ? Am I buying a new domain or creating a CNAME or another kind of record?

As you are owner of mycompany.com you have full right to create subdomain of this domain. The best you can do is to contact support ans ask how to create subdomain in you domain. The in this subdomain create the desired host.

Be aware GoDaddy in documentation all the time name host a subdomain. So explain to support the EXACT situation with examples.
